# Chamada da Action como parametro dentro Html.BeginForm - ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, input, parâmetros, view

tenho um codigo que consulta uma WebApi, grava no banco, e consulta o banco, nesta aplicação, uma view que tem 3 botões, a saber:

- Consultar Ws
- Insere BD
- Consulta BD

Estou utilizando @Html.BeginForm para submeter a ação do botão e chamar a ActionResult responsável por cada processamento.

Na passagem de parametros, só é permitido (obviamente), a chamada de apenas uma action. Como eu faço para fazer que es tenha "uma tomada de decisão" ou um "if", para que chame a a action correta ao se clicar no seu respectivo botão?

Seria melhor utilizar outro tipo de form? Ou quaisquer outras formas para isto?

No codigo abaixo o "ConsultaWs" é a action parametrizada que "deveria mudar" ao se clicar em um botão diferente do "btnCsWs".

```
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("ConsultaWs", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
            <text>codigo do país</text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RestResponse.result.country)
            <text>codigo do estado</text>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RestResponse.result.abbr)
          <button type="submit" name="btnCsWs">Consulta WS</button>
          <button type="submit" name="btnInsereDB">Insere DB</button>
          <button type="submit" name="btnCsDB">Consulta DB</button>
    }
```

Comment: Mauricio, você pode colocar um id no botão e realizar uma chamada Javascript para quando clicado alterar o action do form

Answer (score 1):

Em navegadores que suportam HTML5, você pode usar o atributo `formaction` to botão submit:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("ConsultaWs", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
        <text>codigo do país</text>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RestResponse.result.country)
        <text>codigo do estado</text>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RestResponse.result.abbr)
      <button type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("CsWs", "Home")" name="btnCsWs">Consulta WS</button>
      <button type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("InsereDB", "Home")" name="btnInsereDB">Insere DB</button>
      <button type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("CsDB", "Home")" name="btnCsDB">Consulta DB</button>
}
```

Isso fará com que ao dar submit no form, a requisição vai pro `formaction` do botão clicado.

Em navegadores que não suportam HTML5, você pode adicionar um event listener ao clicar em um botão de tipo `submit` (dá pra melhorar o seletor, delegando a partir de um form específico, por exemplo):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function (event) {
  var action = $(this).attr('formaction');
  $(this).closest('form').attr('action', action);
});
```

O javascript vai aumentar o suporte para navegadores não html5, mas se algum usuário estiver com o javascript desabilitado e o navegador for HTML5, a primeira opção vai permitir que funcione da forma que  você precisa.

Então não tem problema utilizar as duas opções ao mesmo tempo :)

Comment: Phiter, obrigado pela ajuda, eu fiz a primeira opção e serviu muito bem.
Já a segunda, eu não entendi muito bem como fazer, pode me explicar melhor por gentileza?

Comment: A segunda opção, como eu disse, serve para navegadores que não possuem suporte nativo ao atributo `formaction`. O que acontece é  que você colocou um evento de clique delegado para todos os botões de tipo submit. Quando um botão desses for clicado, ele vai alterar a action do form pai para o que está em seu próprio `formaction`, isso antes do submit do form pai.